Would a worldship's warp drive affect the weather?
Background
A while ago I asked about worldships because I'm implementing them in my world and now I have come up to the point where I need to know how to move them around. The obvious issue is that with the approximate mass of Titan it is impractical to equip it with anything other than a warp drive (which the Empire has access to). The biggest possible reaction engines would barely move a worldship around anyways, and as it turns out doing complex alterations to a planet-sized body while in orbit around another planet (potentially with moons) is bound to cause gravitational chaos. The worldship frequently needs to get between star systems anyways, and the navigators of the worldships can get stable warp-drive insertions into planetary orbits within around ~500,000 km with a bit of effort, so the Imperial Financial-Budgetary Division told the engineers not to install a reaction engine at all.
As a result, when a worldship wants to go to a planet (to pick up supplies, to remind the people of the planet that the Empire is watching over them, to deliver supplies/weapons/nuclear weapons to the surface, or for any other reason), a worldship needs to jump directly next to the planet and then stay where it is (to prevent unpredictable orbital perturbations to the planet).
On average worldships mass around $10^{23}$ kilograms (a bit less than Titan); if a worldship were to want to get as close as safely possible to Earth, it would be able to get within around 1,000,000 kilometers; at that distance, the gravitational acceleration from the Sun is still 888 times as much as from the worldship, which is deemed acceptable by the Imperial Celestial Balance Division, since if the worldship is co-orbiting the Sun with that planet for a day or so they can correct that orbital perturbation fairly easily.
Object of interest (for this question)
The warp drive that each worldship is equipped with is built just under the ship's surface and is capable of producing a low-energy spacetime deformation, locally flat within the worldship and extending ~100 kilometers off the surface. At the edge of the bubble, there's a massive energy density that is built up in spacetime curvature, supplied over the course of a long period of time as the warp drive charges (the total energy density is a considerable amount of negative mass-energy; Imperial warp drives are much more efficient than the Alcubierre drive and use a quantum-vacuum method to get the requisite negative energy). When the drive is charged, it causally-disconnects the worldship from the rest of spacetime with a region of extreme curvature at the warp bubble's edge; the causal disconnect allows for the ship to reach much higher velocities than lightspeed without violating causality.
When the warp drive is disengaged, the energy in the warp bubble has to go somewhere. Rather than bleeding it off slowly, it is often safer and more efficient to simply disintegrate the warp bubble all in one go, which results in extremely-intense gravitational radiation, emanating outwards at the speed of light and falling off with the inverse of the square of the distance (great care is taken to direct this radiation outwards so as not to destroy the worldship itself). Normal gravitational radiation has strains on the order of $h\approx10^{-20}$; gravitational radiation emitted by the worldship's warp drive upon disengagement is about $h\approx10^{12}$ (a hundred nonillion times more powerful). This is obviously extremely destructive for anything in the immediate vicinity of the worldship where it appears, but at a distance of 1,000,000 km (which is deemed the minimum distance due to orbital perturbation) detectors on the planet only observe a strain of around $10^{-6}$ (one micrometer per meter, less than one human cell per meter, still very intense but not immediately dangerous to people, mostly).
The question is would such intense gravitational radiation affect the weather of the planet? I would imagine that the sudden strain on the air would equate to some sort of pressure wave that might cause meteorological effects (i.e. sudden cloud/fog formation, moisture level changes, temperature changes, changes in refraction of sunlight, etc). The Imperial worldships' arrival is usually accompanied by a) news coverage and joyous celebration, since there are a great many planets in the Empire and anyone lucky enough to see a worldship in their lifetime should celebrate, and b) other strange weather effects that last a short period. It would be convenient if I could explain the weather effects (I don't especially care what they are, the point is more to point out that something interesting is happening).
Clarifications on the drive's properties:

The radiation emitted by the drive can be effectively approximated as radiating from a point source 1,000,000 km away from an Earth-like planet; the wavefront can be approximated as a plane passing through the planet
The drive doesn't emit electromagnetic radiation of any kind during disengagement; an event intense enough to produce $h\approx10^{12}$ GWs would ordinarily also be powerful enough to destroy the planet utterly at that range (I'm thinking BH collisions, Ia supernovae, other GRB-producing events) but the worldship's technology can contain the other types of radiated energy
If this would ordinarily be super destructive to the planet's inhabitants/life as well, that's okay, I'm concerned only with the weather for now (I can always handwave low-orbit GW protectors that absorb the brunt of it so that biomatter isn't affected)
Any weather effects between in the $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{c}$ seconds after the worldship arrives to anything in the proceeding days/weeks/months is of interest


I'm not an astrophysicist, so let's ask a simple question. What's the gravitational radiation effect on the Earth? What this really boils down to is how much additional tide will be created by your worldship's appearance? Increase the tide even 10% and you're wiping out coastal life regardless the effect on the weather (and then it affects the weather). So, let's simplify the question: how much is that dissipating warp bubble changing the tide?

So the worldships are ~1.3 times the weight of the moon, and parking ~3 times farther away than the moon, that's going to create ~50mm of Earth-Tide, 14.4% of the lunar contribution. That's the sustained effect of these ships being in orbit and  it will create massive earthquakes, the matching oceanic tides will totally destroy all coastal infrastructure.
The arrival energy is enough that it should strip the atmosphere, and probably some of the ocean, off the world, period. Assuming the world survives in some kind of habitable shape then the gravitational radiation is ultimately going to be expressed as heat in everything it effects. That's going to heat the atmosphere, the ocean, the crust, the mantle, etc... quite a lot, and it's going to effect all those parts of the world equally. I can't put exact numbers to the temperature bump but it's going to be catastrophic.

Mm, didn’t consider the tidal forces… that will be something to think about.
